# Pandas DataFrame not working as intended

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I am new to Python and I'm trying to use it for finance, specifically plotting stock prices. I am using pandas and its `DataFrame` object, but for some reason I cannot obtain the data I need. The `web.DataReader` method works, as I tried it in another program, but my code does not. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pandas.io.data as web

symbols = ['AAPL', 'MSFT', 'GLD']
data=pd.DataFrame()
for sym in symbols:
    data[sym] = web.DataReader(sym, data_source='yahoo', start='4/14/2014',end='01/30/2015')['Adj Close']
data.columns=symbols
print(data['AAPL'])
```

The output is an empty dataframe and I am not sure why, because `DataReader` does work as I tried it elsewhere.

Comment: Step into the `for` loop and check if `web.DataReader(...)` is in fact retrieving the expected values.

Comment: Works for me. What pandas version are you using? `pd.__version__`

Comment: I get nonempty output when I run your code.  Is there anything else in your code that you haven't posted?  Also, the line `data.columns = symbols` is not necessary, as you're already assigning the same column names in your `for` loop.

Comment: @iled That's the problem, I don't know why it isn't retrieving the expected values. If I do data= [...] instead of data[sym] =[...] and then call print(data) it will only print the values for the first symbol entered. I can retrieve the data just fine from web.DataReader() for individual stocks (one symbol at a time), but not for a list of them as shown above.

Comment: @user1222 I got that, I suggested that you debug it, step into the for loop, and analyze what `web.DataReader` is returning in each iteration. Or just print it out, if that's easier. Also, post the info requested in the other comments please.

Comment: @MikeMüller Pandas version is 0.11.0, maybe that's the problem?

Comment: @iled Here is the output when I print every iteration:
Series([], dtype: float64)
Series([], dtype: float64)
Series([], dtype: float64)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An update of pandas to version >=0.17.1 should solve your problem. If you use `conda`  (recommended) :

```
conda update pandas
```

will do.

After the update you will get a deprecation warning.

To avoid this install `pandas-datareader`:

```
conda install pandas-datareader
```

and change:

```
import pandas.io.data as web
```

into:

```
from pandas_datareader import data as web
```